# How to call an a callbacks when I take an a type of autorization?

Tags: python, django

I have got a project, which have an autorization by vk and google. I need to call funcitions like vk_callback or google_callback when i make autorization by this types. Hoe can i do it?
views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Home Page')


def vk_callback(request):
    user_info_getter = UserInfoGetter(request.user, 'vk-oauth2')
    take_info = user_info_getter.get_user_info_vk()
    if take_info:
        name, last_name, photo = take_info
        print(name, last_name, photo, sep='\n')
    return redirect(home)


def google_callback(request):
    user_info_getter = UserInfoGetter(request.user, 'google-oauth2')
    take_info = user_info_getter.get_user_info_google()
    if take_info:
        name, last_name, photo = take_info
        print(name, last_name, photo, sep='\n')
    return redirect(home)
```

I try to make it by url-address, but it doesn't work:
urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('vk/callback/', views.vk_callback, name='vk_callback'),
    path('google/callback/', views.google_callback, name='google_callback')
]
```

After successful authorization takes info from server:

```
"GET /complete/google-oauth2/?state=Qw2iyDHL9w6ueu4aKU8cfx7lC4VKjEgN&code=4%2F0AbUR2VMMND7R2atmHBSbfGxtlbRBzTwiMnsiSpcYAmLI2cQeKuK7D1b_iUJ6uc2Pgp863w&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.ema
il+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&authuser=0&prompt=none HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```